# Page numbers at the bottom in lyx

Tags: lyx, page-numbering

How to add page numbers at the bottom center of page in LYX? The page numbers are not coming properly. The document class is book.
By adding the following code in preamble

```
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ofoot{\arabic{page}}
\ohead{}
```

The page numbers come at the bottom. but not at the center. how to center the page numbers?

Comment: Use `\cfoot` instead `\ofoot`: `\cfoot{\pagemark}`.

Comment: the solution worked. In my chapter the name of the chapter appears in the header. How can that be removed?

Comment: How to decrease the font size of chapter name in header? Another question is if I use the package underline to underline the header, page number appears along with it. How to remove the page number?

Comment: To change the fontsize in header you can use `\addtokomafont{pagehead}{...}` or  `\setkomafont`. But I thought you want to  remove the chapter name from header? Regarding `underline` please ask a new question with a MWE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use package `scrlayer-scrpage` that is the successor of `scrpage2`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note that `scrlayer-scrpage` sets the page stlye `scrheadings` by default.

---

With **`scrpage2`**:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: is there a pagestyle other than `scrheadings` to include chapter names at the top/bottom of the page?

Comment: @Sparkler Using `scrlayer-scrpage` you can define a your own new page style. But why? Or do you want to use a different package like `fancyhdr`? Maybe its better to ask a new question with a MWE for your problem.