# Chapter name in header

Tags: header-footer

How can the following three be done

1. Reduce the font size in chapter name in header.
2. remove subsections name appearing in the header.
3. underlining in the header.
4. page numbers only at the center bottom of the page and not in the header.

Chapter header is required here.

Comment: `Header` isn't unique. Do you mean page header or chapter header?

Comment: And now add a working document as a starter please ;-) Achieving you multiple requests depends on the documentclass

Comment: You can do that with `fancyhdr` or, perhaps simpler to use, `titletoc`.

Comment: How can I bold the text in header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a follow up question of [Page numbers at the bottom in lyx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285342/43317) and you want to "underline" the complete header:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\usepackage[
  headsepline,
  %plainheadsepline% headsepline also on plain pages
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\tiny}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\headmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]